# Installing SimpleSAMLphp on Windows

Tags: saml, saml-2.0, shibboleth

I have PHP installed on my windows instance, have copied across the folder.

On running the script I get the following error.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Unable to load Composer autoloader' in C:\Users\Chris\Dropbox\WEBSITES\php_tests\lib\_autoload.php:18
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\Chris\Dropbox\WEBSITES\php_tests\login\_include.php(32): require_once()
#1 C:\Users\Chris\Dropbox\WEBSITES\php_tests\login\index.php(3): require_once('C:\\Users\\Chris\\...')
#2 {main}
  thrown in C:\Users\Chris\Dropbox\WEBSITES\php_tests\lib\_autoload.php on line 18
```

I can't work out how to fix.

Comment: Some more detail would be helpful. Details like you are using shibboleth SP or IdP or plain SAML, how you have configured these, etc.

Comment: @Akshay I am trying to integrate our system as a Shibboleth service provider.

Answer (score 0):

Go [here](https://simplesamlphp.org/download) to download the latest simplesamlphp as described [here](https://simplesamlphp.org/docs/stable/simplesamlphp-install). This file will probably end in `.tar.gz` and comes with required dependencies like Composer autoloader.

Do not download the latest from the github. This file will probably end in `.zip` and it doesn't come with required dependencies like Composer autoloader. Using this file for install can lead to an error like mention in your question.